# How can I disable an Animator from the Animation in Unity?

Tags: unity, animation, animator

How can I disable an **Animator** from the **Animation** in Unity?

The **Animator** enablement checkbox seems to be highlighted, which makes me believe that the enablement of the **Animator** is an animatable property itself. But whenever I try to animate it the enablement toggling just does not get recorded onto the animation line.

[image]

It feels like I am missing something here. If someone notices me doing something wrong, could you, please, point it out.

Answer (score 1):

When you use the animation time-line, Unity will automatically disable the animator component, even if you aren't trying to modify it. Try implementing the animation and then seeing if it will work.

Comment: Do you maybe happen to know a place in documentation which would prove what you are saying?

Comment: What does it even mean to implement an animation and see later if it works? I can clearly see that the **Animator** enablement property does not get added into an animation.

Comment: Make it so when the character dies, it plays the animation and see if the animator component gets disabled when it plays in the game.

Comment: It does not get disabled.